# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract')

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract')

Module.

lottery-react/src/lottery.js:9

I get this error when I serve and go to the browser

[image]

My code

```
import web3 from "web3";

const address = '0x------------------------------';


const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPlayers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"enter","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"players","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}];


function test () {
    console.log(web3.eth); // throws undefined 
};

export default test;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by making a minor change

update `web3.eth`

to `new web3().eth`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
const web3 = require('web3');
```

I needed to do this:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();
```

Answer (score 0):

`web3.eth` is undefined. Try fixing that first.

Comment: please how can I fix that? I cannot console.log web3.eth and I deployed the contract successfully.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot console.log web3.eth? Have you done `console.log(web3.eth)`?

Comment: i get undefined. i just updated my question to include my code @Shivam

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your contract

kindly do it and then call your smart contract method

```
var contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```